# how to resolve This tkinter proplem?

Tags: python, tkinter

this is the code:

```
def Download():
url = link_ent.get()
Selceted= types.get()
if len(url) < 1:
    link_error.config(text = "الرجاء ادخال موقع الفيديو")
if len(direct) < 1:
    path_error.config(text = "الرجاء ادخال مكان تنزيل الملف")
else:
    link.config(text="")
    path_error.config(text="")
    try:
        Yt = YouTube(url)
        try:
            if (Selceted == options[0]):
                typ = Yt.streams.filter(progressive=True,file_extension="mp4").first()
            elif (Selceted == options[1]):
                typ = Yt.streams.get_lowest_resolution()
            elif (Selceted == options[2]):
                typ = Yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
                try:
                    typ.download(direct)
                    link_ent.delete(0,"end")
                    path_holder.config(text = "\t\t\t\t    ")
                    download_out.config(text= "تم التحميل" , font = (12))

                    name = typ.title
                    size = typ.filesize/1024000
                    size = round(size,1)
                    download_name.config(text=" الاسم " + name)
                    download_size.config(text=" الحجم " + str(size)+ "ميغا بايت")
                    download_loc.config(text=" موقع الملف " + direct)
                except:
                    download_out.config(text = "فشل التحميل" , font=(12))

    except:
        path_error.config(text = "الرجاء ادخال مكان تنزيل صالح!")
```

and I have this error

```
File "C:\Users\baraa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\folder\baraa.py", line 53
    except:
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a "Try:" block but you dont have a "except:" block. If you add it, it will fix i suppose.
here:

```
try:
        if (Selceted == options[0]):
            typ = Yt.streams.filter(progressive=True,file_extension="mp4").first()
        elif (Selceted == options[1]):
            typ = Yt.streams.get_lowest_resolution()
        elif (Selceted == options[2]):
            typ = Yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
            try:
                typ.download(direct)
                link_ent.delete(0,"end")
                path_holder.config(text = "\t\t\t\t    ")
                download_out.config(text= "تم التحميل" , font = (12))

                name = typ.title
                size = typ.filesize/1024000
                size = round(size,1)
                download_name.config(text=" الاسم " + name)
                download_size.config(text=" الحجم " + str(size)+ "ميغا بايت")
                download_loc.config(text=" موقع الملف " + direct)
            except:
                download_out.config(text = "فشل التحميل" , font=(12))
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Wrong. The ```try...except``` block should have the same indentation. Other wise, they are 2 separate blocks with no connection between them

Comment: its the same error What do i do

Comment: @Sujay yeah i'm thinking the same. I pasted the code to show where the error is. There is a "try" block, but there is no "except" on the same indentation

Comment: I did not make any changes in the code I posted above, I posted it the same way. I just stated that he should add a except block

Comment: i dont understand what you are talking but can you send me a code after edit?

Comment: Hi again, i edited the code

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `except` block. You have 3 `try...` blocks but only 2 `except` blocks.

Also, **don't use bare `except`. It will suppress all errors and exceptions. Sometimes, the errors contain useful information which needs to be used for fixing bugs.**

```
    try:
        Yt = YouTube(url)
        try:
            if (Selceted == options[0]):
                typ = Yt.streams.filter(progressive=True,file_extension="mp4").first()
            elif (Selceted == options[1]):
                typ = Yt.streams.get_lowest_resolution()
            elif (Selceted == options[2]):
                typ = Yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
                try:
                    typ.download(direct)
                    link_ent.delete(0,"end")
                    path_holder.config(text = "\t\t\t\t    ")
                    download_out.config(text= "تم التحميل" , font = (12))

                    name = typ.title
                    size = typ.filesize/1024000
                    size = round(size,1)
                    download_name.config(text=" الاسم " + name)
                    download_size.config(text=" الحجم " + str(size)+ "ميغا بايت")
                    download_loc.config(text=" موقع الملف " + direct)
                except:
                    download_out.config(text = "فشل التحميل" , font=(12))
        except:
            pass  

    except:
        path_error.config(text = "الرجاء ادخال مكان تنزيل صالح!")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baraa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\folder\baraa.py", line 88, in <module>
    path_btn = Button(window,width=11,text= "Selcet Path " ,style="PT.TButton",command= openpath())
  File "C:\Users\baraa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\folder\baraa.py", line 11, in openpath
    download_out.config(text="من الطبيعي عدم استجابة الكمبيوتر عند التحميل")
NameError: name 'download_out' is not defined

Comment: @BaraaJawish I suggest you take up some good python tutorials or look up those errors on the internet, you have plenty. The error you are encountering, are some of the most basic errors that can be corrected easily.

Comment: ok but now what is the solution